# Android Studio - Basic Calculator - app shows unfortunately stopped

Tags: android

I am new at using android studio. I tried this code and built and generated an unsigned apk. I tried in on Samsung galaxy trend GT-s7392 and Asus Zenfone 5, also tried in bluestacks. But when the app is opened , It shows - " Unfortunately Calculator has stopped.?"

Additionally, It never asks for for any permission upon installation. Should i need to  modify the android manifest.xml or any other file

```
package in.harisree.calculator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public abstract class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener {

    public Button btnAdd,btnSub,btnMul,btnDiv;
    public TextView tvResult;
    public EditText etNum1,etNum2;
    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        init();

    }

    private void init() {
        btnAdd=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        btnSub=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSub);
        btnMul=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnMul);
        btnDiv=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDiv);
        etNum1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etNum1);
        etNum2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etNum2);
        tvResult=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvResult);

        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnSub.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnMul.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnDiv.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        String a= String.valueOf(etNum1.getText());
        String b= String.valueOf(etNum1.getText());

        switch (view.getId())
        {
            case R.id.btnAdd:
                tvResult.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(a)+Integer.parseInt(b)));
                break;
            case R.id.btnSub:
                tvResult.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(a)-Integer.parseInt(b)));
                break;
            case R.id.btnMul:
                tvResult.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(a)*Integer.parseInt(b)));
                break;
            case R.id.btnDiv:
                tvResult.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(a)/Integer.parseInt(b)));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

here is the logcat

```html
02-14 18:34:44.287 15923-15923/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
02-14 18:34:44.437 15923-15923/in.harisree.calculator V/Monotype: SetAppTypeFace- try to flip, app = in.harisree.calculator
02-14 18:34:44.437 15923-15923/in.harisree.calculator V/Monotype:     Typeface getFontPathFlipFont - systemFont = default
02-14 18:34:44.457 15923-15923/in.harisree.calculator D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
02-14 18:34:44.457 15923-15923/in.harisree.calculator E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-14 18:34:44.457 15923-15923/in.harisree.calculator E/AndroidRuntime: Process: in.harisree.calculator, PID: 15923
02-14 18:34:44.457 15923-15923/in.harisree.calculator E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{in.harisree.calculator/in.harisree.calculator.MainActivity}: java.lang.InstantiationException: class in.harisree.calculator.MainActivity cannot be instantiated
02-14 18:34:44.457 15923-15923/in.harisree.calculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2227)
02-14 18:34:44.457 15923-15923/in.harisree.calculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376)
02-14 18:34:44.457 15923-15923/in.harisree.calculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:147)
02-14 18:34:44.457 15923-15923/in.harisree.calculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
02-14 18:34:44.457 15923-15923/in.harisree.calculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-14 18:34:44.457 15923-15923/in.harisree.calculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
02-14 18:34:44.457 15923-15923/in.harisree.calculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5253)
02-14 18:34:44.457 15923-15923/in.harisree.calculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-14 18:34:44.457 15923-15923/in.harisree.calculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-14 18:34:44.457 15923-15923/in.harisree.calculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
02-14 18:34:44.457 15923-15923/in.harisree.calculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
02-14 18:34:44.457 15923-15923/in.harisree.calculator E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: class in.harisree.calculator.MainActivity cannot be instantiated
02-14 18:34:44.457 15923-15923/in.harisree.calculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1553)
02-14 18:34:44.457 15923-15923/in.harisree.calculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1065)
02-14 18:34:44.457 15923-15923/in.harisree.calculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2217)
02-14 18:34:44.457 15923-15923/in.harisree.calculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376) 
02-14 18:34:44.457 15923-15923/in.harisree.calculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:147) 
02-14 18:34:44.457 15923-15923/in.harisree.calculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281) 
02-14 18:34:44.457 15923-15923/in.harisree.calculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
02-14 18:34:44.457 15923-15923/in.harisree.calculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
02-14 18:34:44.457 15923-15923/in.harisree.calculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5253) 
02-14 18:34:44.457 15923-15923/in.harisree.calculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
02-14 18:34:44.457 15923-15923/in.harisree.calculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
02-14 18:34:44.457 15923-15923/in.harisree.calculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
02-14 18:34:44.457 15923-15923/in.harisree.calculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: add your Error message from your log

Comment: How did you build it? Please include the steps you took.

Comment: does it work when you debug it (i.e. without installing through an apk)?

Comment: Generally, no matter what type of device you run your code on, it will crash if the code is bad. As the others say, if you don't post your logcat, then no one will be able to effectively help you

Comment: solved. an abstract in the main was the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the abstract (if this is the activity which defined in your manifest). Because the android.app.Instrumentation wont be able to instantiate that activity when you run your application. You can create a base abstract activity and your MainAcitvity can extend it.

your code should throw this exception 
java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class in.harisree.calculator.MainActivity

Answer (score 0):

While implementing OnClickListener make sure to override onClickListerner.

```
package in.harisree.calculator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public abstract class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener {

public Button btnAdd,btnSub,btnMul,btnDiv;
public TextView tvResult;
public EditText etNum1,etNum2;
@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    init();

}

private void init() {
    btnAdd=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    btnSub=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSub);
    btnMul=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnMul);
    btnDiv=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDiv);
    etNum1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etNum1);
    etNum2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etNum2);
    tvResult=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvResult);

    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnSub.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnMul.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnDiv.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    String a= String.valueOf(etNum1.getText());
    String b= String.valueOf(etNum1.getText());

    switch (view.getId())
    {
        case R.id.btnAdd:
            tvResult.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(a)+Integer.parseInt(b)));
            break;
        case R.id.btnSub:
            tvResult.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(a)-Integer.parseInt(b)));
            break;
        case R.id.btnMul:
            tvResult.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(a)*Integer.parseInt(b)));
            break;
        case R.id.btnDiv:
            tvResult.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(a)/Integer.parseInt(b)));
            break;
    }
}
}
```